# Finding minimum date from a list in Drools

Tags: drools

I have an object "Parent" which contains a list of "Item" objects. Each "Item" has a ship date. How do I find the minimum ship date from the list of "Item" objects? I'm using Drools 6.2.0.

```
class Parent{
    List<Item> items;
    // Getter / Setter
}

class Item{
    Date shipDate();
    // Getter / Setter
}
```

I tried coming up with a rule, but it throws an exception. I'm pretty sure I'm way off. This is what I have for now:

```
rule "Print min ship date"
    when
        $parent : Parent( $items:getItems() && null != $items)
        $minShipDate : Date() from accumulate(($item : Item ($shipDate : getShipDate()) from $items), 
                                    min($shipDate)) 
    then
        System.out.println("Min ship date is "+minShipDate); 
end
```

This is the exception I get:

```
 java.lang.ClassCastException: org.drools.compiler.lang.descr.OrDescr cannot be cast to org.drools.compiler.lang.descr.PatternDescr
```

Comment: This rule doesn't throw the exception you reported.

Comment: @laune Is the rule that I have correct? Not sure why it's throwing that exception for me. Any idea what this exception means?

Comment: If you post something, make sure it does what you say it does. The rule you have posted doesn't even compile.

Answer (score 1):

**The exception stated in the question is not thrown by this rule - even after fixing the syntax error.**

But there is a problem: Drools cannot handle java.util.Date in accumulate's min and max functions. One has to employ a somewhat tedious workaround:

```
rule "Print min ship date"
when
    $parent: Parent( $items: items != null )
    accumulate( Item( $shipDate: shipDate ) from $items, 
                $msd: min($shipDate.getTime()) ) 
then
    System.out.println("Min ship date is " + new Date($msd.longValue())); 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Accumulate is bad. It uses a lot of resources.

Also min($shipDate) returns a Comparable() so you might need to cast it to Comparable() but if you need to compare it to another date it won't work.

You can get the minShipDate following this example:

```
    rule "Print min ship date"
        when
            $parent: Parent(items != null)
            $child: Item() from $parent.items
            not Item(shipDate< $child.shipDate) from $parent.items // there is no Item with shipDate lower than $child.shipDate
        then
            System.out.println("Min ship date is " + $child.minShipDate); 
    end
```